# Is the PHP Manual misguiding regarding the output of 'phpinfo()' function?

Tags: php, php-internals

I'm using **Windows 10 Home Single Language Edition** which is a **64-bit Operating System** on my machine.

I've installed the most latest version of **XAMPP** which has installed **PHP 7.2.6** on my machine.

I come across the following sentence from the paragraph in [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php#example-3)

> Make a call to the phpinfo() function and you will see a lot of useful
>   information about your system and setup such as **available predefined
>   variables**, loaded PHP modules, and configuration settings.

I tried executing the below script and saw the output in my web browser :

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I checked the entire output carefully. In the output of `phpinfo()` I could only see the `$_SERVER` predefined variable along with it's possible indexes specific to set-up on my machine.

But what about other predefined variables in PHP viz. **$GLOBALS, $_GET, $_POST, $_FILES, $_COOKIE, $_SESSION, $_REQUEST, $_ENV, $http_response_header, $argc, $argv**?

According to what the text from [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php#example-3) is saying all the above mentioned predefined variables along with their respective values should be displayed in the output of the script `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` but it's not happening. Why so?

Is the text from PHP manual misguiding the users of PHP?

Or am I getting the wrong understanding of the text from PHP Manual?

Please explain me in detail.

Comment: did you put `phpinfo();` at the end of your script or as a new file? if it was a new file then clearly there's no context.

Comment: have you posted to the page with `phpinfo()`? are there any variables in the url? you wont see what does not exist.

Comment: @Scuzzy : the only content I put in my .php file is <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: then there is noting to show in those variables, they simply wont be populated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [PHP source code for `phpinfo()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/info.c#L984), it will display the variables in question:

```
    if (flag & PHP_INFO_VARIABLES) {
        zval *data;

        SECTION("PHP Variables");

        php_info_print_table_start();
        php_info_print_table_header(2, "Variable", "Value");
        if ((data = zend_hash_str_find(&EG(symbol_table), "PHP_SELF", sizeof("PHP_SELF")-1)) != NULL && Z_TYPE_P(data) == IS_STRING) {
            php_info_print_table_row(2, "PHP_SELF", Z_STRVAL_P(data));
        }
        if ((data = zend_hash_str_find(&EG(symbol_table), "PHP_AUTH_TYPE", sizeof("PHP_AUTH_TYPE")-1)) != NULL && Z_TYPE_P(data) == IS_STRING) {
            php_info_print_table_row(2, "PHP_AUTH_TYPE", Z_STRVAL_P(data));
        }
        if ((data = zend_hash_str_find(&EG(symbol_table), "PHP_AUTH_USER", sizeof("PHP_AUTH_USER")-1)) != NULL && Z_TYPE_P(data) == IS_STRING) {
            php_info_print_table_row(2, "PHP_AUTH_USER", Z_STRVAL_P(data));
        }
        if ((data = zend_hash_str_find(&EG(symbol_table), "PHP_AUTH_PW", sizeof("PHP_AUTH_PW")-1)) != NULL && Z_TYPE_P(data) == IS_STRING) {
            php_info_print_table_row(2, "PHP_AUTH_PW", Z_STRVAL_P(data));
        }
        php_print_gpcse_array(ZEND_STRL("_REQUEST"));
        php_print_gpcse_array(ZEND_STRL("_GET"));
        php_print_gpcse_array(ZEND_STRL("_POST"));
        php_print_gpcse_array(ZEND_STRL("_FILES"));
        php_print_gpcse_array(ZEND_STRL("_COOKIE"));
        php_print_gpcse_array(ZEND_STRL("_SERVER"));
        php_print_gpcse_array(ZEND_STRL("_ENV"));
        php_info_print_table_end();
}
```

However, as you can see, it uses [`php_print_gpcse_array`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/info.c#L191) to print each key/value pair in it when a) the superglobal exists (SAPI dependent) and b) it actually contains values.

**TL;DR:** no, the PHP manual is not misleading in that regard.